# Where is DropWhile in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Mathematica 6 added `TakeWhile`, which has the syntax:

> TakeWhile[*list*, *crit*]
>   gives elements *e*<sub>i</sub> from the beginning of *list*, continuing so long as *crit*[e<sub>i</sub>] is True.

There is however no corresponding "DropWhile" function.  One can construct DropWhile using `LengthWhile` and `Drop`, but it almost seems as though one is discouraged from using DropWhile.  Why is this?

To clarify, I am not asking for a way to implement this function.  Rather: why is it not already present?  It seems to me that there must be a reason for its absence other than an oversight, or it would have been corrected by now.  Is there something inefficient, undesirable, or superfluous about DropWhile?

---

There appears to be some ambiguity about the function of DropWhile, so here is an example:

```
DropWhile = Drop[#, LengthWhile[#, #2]] &;

DropWhile[{1,2,3,4,5}, # <= 3 &]
```

```
Out= {4, 5}
```

Comment: On the "ambiguity". This is just a language ambiguity of the word "while". We should follow standard meaning of "while" used in such functions as `While` in *Mathematica*. So your problem could be rewritten as `list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
While[list[[1]] <= 3, list = Drop[list, 1]]; list`. There is no any ambiguity as I can see.

Comment: @Alexey, my edit was in response to an answer that suggested a method that did not agree with the definition above.  It has since been deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ubiquitous Lists in Mathematica are fixed length vectors, and when they are of a machine numbers it is a packed array.

Thus the natural functions for a recursively defined linked list (e.g. in Lisp or Haskell) are not the primary tools in Mathematica.

So I am inclined to think this explains why Wolfram did not fill out its repertoire of manipulation functions.

Answer (score 7):

Just a blind guess.

There are a lot list operations that could take a **while** criteria. For example:

```
Total..While  
Accumulate..While  
Mean..While  
Map..While  
Etc..While
```

They are not difficult to construct, anyway.

I think those are not included just because the number of "primitive" functions is already growing too long, and the criteria of "is it frequently needed and difficult to implement with good performance by the user?" is prevailing in those cases.

Comment: By this logic, would not `TakeWhile` also be absent since it can be constructed from `LengthWhile`?  It seems to me that `Take` and `Drop` go together as a pair, and I believe that other languages that implement this have both takeWhile and dropWhile.  I think I like the idea of MapWhile, by the way.

Comment: @Mr. I think the existence of TakeWhile and LengthWhile is not curious because orthogonality is not the prevailing criteria for function implementation at WR. However, we are just ranting here. I just want to add that I've had to make my own dropWhile quite a few times :)

Comment: I wonder if the explosion could be tamed by having the different functions accept an alternative second (or, whatever) parameter that indicated the test to be performed. That way it would make `Take`, etc., orthogonal to its condition generator.

Comment: @rcollyer Probably. But that could make Mma learning curve steeper, an undesirable thing, I guess.

Comment: probably, true. gone are the days of exploring mma through the fantastic tree structure of the help system.